# How pass value of variable from javascript to jsp on same page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, combobox, web-development-server

I created two combo boxes. when i choose any value from first combo box respectively the values from second combo box should be changed.

i am using String xyz=request.getParameter("combo1") ;

where combo1 is the name or id of the combo box.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please frame your question in a way others can understand. And put the code also what you have tried.
Anyways seems like you want to set some value from change event of others, with the simple js function we can do
 please see the code

```
 <script>
 function doChange() 
 {
   var val = document.getElementById("mydropdown").value;
   var e = document.getElementById("mydropdown2");
   e.innerHTML="";  
   e.options[e.options.length] = new Option(val, val);
 }
</script>
<form>
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="doChange()">
<option value="Sample1">Sample1</option>
<option value="Sample2">Sample2</option>
<option value="Sample3">Sample3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select name="mydropdown2" id="mydropdown2" >
</select>
```